# Security of passing sensitive data into Node.js exec() function's stdin

Tags: command-line, bash, shell, node.js, credentials

I've been thinking of using Node.js's `exec()` function to run a command line utility. This requires credentials to be passed in after executing the command.

I know passing in sensitive data into the command itself is considered a really bad practice, as this would be logged in the shell command history.

I'm curious about the implications of passing them into the stdin, and if it makes any difference if it's the command line directly or it it's being executed by the `exec()` function.